# Trying to run Django and getting AttributeError: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: django

'''
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 18, in handle
options['secret_key'] = get_random_secret_key()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/utils.py", line 82, in get_random_secret_key
return get_random_string(50, chars)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/crypto.py", line 74, in get_random_string
return ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/crypto.py", line 74, in 
return ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length))
AttributeError: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'choice'
'''

Comment: Fixed it. I accidentally deleted the secrets file and put one of my secret keys as secrets.py

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you don't have any file or folders named `secrets.py` or `secrets` anywhere in your python path and/or current working directory. That may shadow the built in `secrets` module.

Comment: ^^ this was the solution for me, I ran across this same error. I had created a `secrets.py` file for a Flask app, but then decided to use environment variables set via the CLI instead, and left the `secrets.py` file blank. This caused this error, but only when Flask was in development / debug mode, it worked fine in prod. TIL!